# How to Call function from Component.ts file in service.ts file which is in the same component in angular

Tags: angular, api, local-storage, angular-directive, angular-services

**I have tried the external shared service method but it doesn't work**

**1) This is my UpdateBankComponent.ts file where I am calling a post api named getSearchBank() using the api-service.ts file But the main problem is that I have a function in this component named getBankById() which gets the updated bank Id and calls a get API and displays the response of get api on the html page.**

```
export class UpdateBankComponent implements OnInit { 

constructor(private _newApiService : ApiServiceService , private http : HttpClient, public router: Router ,  private sharedser : SharedService ) {}

 getSearchBankAPI(postData : Create , postForm : NgForm ){
    this._newApiService.getSearchBank(
      postData.address,
       postData.bankId,
      postData.bankName,
      postData.branch,
      postData.ifscCode,
       postData.passBookNo
      
      )
     
   console.log("Search Customer API Called!!");
   postForm.reset();
  
  console.log("Bank IFSC")
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue"))

   
  if (this.sharedser.clickEventSubscription==undefined) {    
    this.sharedser.clickEventSubscription = this.sharedser.    
    getClickEvent().subscribe(() => {
      console.log("Click Event subscription")
     this.getBankById();
     })
  }   
  
  }
  

 

     public  getBankById(){
     console.log( "Bank Id before get bank by Id :" + localStorage.getItem("BankId"))
  return this.http.get<Create[]>('http://localhost:9900/api/v1/bank/' + localStorage.getItem("BankId"))
  .subscribe((responseData : Create[])=>
  {
    const x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseData));
    let arr: any[] = [];  
    arr.push(x.body)   
     this.response = arr;
    console.log(this.response)
         });  

  } }
```

**2) This is my api-service.ts which is in ths same component**

```
export class ApiServiceService {
  specificBankId: void | undefined;

  constructor(private http : HttpClient ,  private sharedser : SharedService ) { }
  response : Create[] | undefined ; 
  bankifsc = localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue")

  public getSearchBank(
   
    address: {
      addressDetails: string,
    city: string,
      country: string,
      pincode: string,
      state: string
    },
   
    bankId: string,
    bankName: string,
    branch: string,
    ifscCode: string,
     passBookNo : string
    ){
const postData : Create = {
  ifscCode: ifscCode,
  address: {
    addressDetails: '',
    city: '',
    country: '',
    pincode: '',
    state: ''
  },
  bankId: '',
  bankName: '',
  branch: '',
  passBookNo: ''
}
{
return this.http.post('http://localhost:9900/api/v1/bank/search',postData)
.subscribe((responseData)=>
{
  var response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseData));
  const specificbank = response.body.find((el: { ifscCode: string | null; }) => el.ifscCode === localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue"));
    console.log("IFSC CODES ARE ===" + specificbank.ifscCode + " " + localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue"))
     if (specificbank) {
        this.specificBankId =  localStorage.setItem("BankId", specificbank.bankId);
        this.callMe()
      //  localStorage.setItem("customerId", (response.body.customerId));
     }
  console.log("Search Bank called from Update bank Component!!")
  console.log(responseData);
  console.log("Bank ifsc code entered is !!")
   console.log(localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue"))

  console.log("Specific Bank id is ")
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("BankId"))
  
  
  });  
    }
  }

  callMe(){
    this.specificBankId
    console.log("Click Event sent!!")
    this.sharedser.sendClickEvent();
  }
```

**Now the main problem is that in this getSearchBank() where I am calling post api , here in**

`this.specificBankId =  localStorage.setItem("BankId", specificbank.bankId);`

**I am storing the updated bankId so what I want is to call the function getBankById() which is in Component.ts file after the bankId is updated**

**I want to call this getBankById() function here**

```
 if (specificbank) {
        this.specificBankId =  localStorage.setItem("BankId", specificbank.bankId);
        this.getBankById()
      
     }
```

**SO how can I do this , I have tried the shared service method but i also dosent works**
**This is the shared service code**

```
export class SharedService {
  // private subject = new Subject<any>();
   private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
   clickEventSubscription : Subscription | undefined;
  

    sendClickEvent(){
      this.subject.next;
    }

    getClickEvent():Observable<any>{
      return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

  

}
```

** Also this is my html code for displaying the getBankById() data , I want to display the details that is why I have to declare this function in the .ts component itself otherwise I would have straight away declared it in the service.ts file**

```
  <form #postForm="ngForm"   (ngSubmit)="getSearchBankAPI(postForm.value , postForm)" >
                      
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">IFSCCode</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="ifscCode" (input)="onKey($event)">
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <table class="table" border="1">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">Bank Name</th>
                              <th scope="col">Branch</th>
                              <th scope="col">IFSCCode</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr *ngFor="let el of response">
                                <th scope="col">{{el.bankName}}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{{el.branch}}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{{el.ifscCode}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            
                            </thead>
                        
                          </table>
                     
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--red" type="submit" required >See Bank Details</button> | 
                           
                        </div>
                      
                    </form>
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("BankId", specificbank.bankId)` doesn't return any value, to get the value you need to use `this.specificBankId =  localStorage.getItem("BankId")`

Answer (score 0):

Move `getBankById()` into `ApiServiceService`. Then to call it from `UpdateBankComponent` just use `this._newApiService.getBankById()`

You can easily call a service function from a component, but you can't easily call a component function from a service, **nor should you**. So if both files need the function, it should be in the service.

Comment: Ya I can do that but the problem is that I want to display its data on the html page using ngfor . I have created a response array and I am storing the getBankById() response body in this array and then I am using ngfor to display the data . But if i move the getBankId() to service then I wont be able to display the data using this response array.

Comment: Like I said, you can still call the function with `this._newApiService.getBankById()`

Comment: Like If i do this then how can I use ngfor to display the data of an array which is not present in the component.ts file but in the service.ts file .  It gives me this error :: 

Property 'response' does not exist on type 'UpdateBankComponent'.ngtsc(2339)
update-bank.component.ts(14, 2): Error occurs in the template of component UpdateBankComponent.

Comment: I believe you can pass your array as a parameter to the service

Comment: To be honest though, this code needs a serious redesign. Why not just return the observables in your service, and subscribe in the component?